# The DataReader Is Incompatible

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created the EF model and then in a Class I have written the following Code to retrieve the value form the DataBase. And store the value in another Table. But it gives me the Error "DATAREADER IS INCompatable" as explained Below..

```
      EmpRole empr = new EmpRole();
        empr.EmpId = strEmpId;
      string str="select RoleId from RoleName where roleName like '"+strDesignation+"'";
      var context= DbAccess.Data.ExecuteStoreQuery<RoleName>(str, null);  //Here Showing Error

        empr.RoleId = Convert.ToInt16(context);
        DbAccess.Data.EmpRoles.AddObject(empr);
        DbAccess.Commit();
```

It's showing the error like:

DataTables were:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoleName](
    [SNo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RoleName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RoleId] ASC
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpRoles](
    [Sno] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmpId] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [ReportingToId] [varchar](8) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmpRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Sno] ASC
)
```

The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MyOrgDBModel.RoleName'. A member of the type, 'SNo', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Please tell me the reasons what to do to execute the sqlQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not selecting the SNo column in your select query. As you are populating in RoleName and it has property SNo column should be present in data reader. If you just want the RoleId to be in query then create new type with one property RoleId and use this. Create new type like below

```
public class CustomRoleName
{
    int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

Now change your code as follow

```
EmpRole empr = new EmpRole();
empr.EmpId = strEmpId;
string str="select RoleId from RoleName where roleName like '"+strDesignation+"'";
foreach(CustomRoleName rn in  DbAccess.Data.ExecuteStoreQuery<CustomRoleName>(str))
{
     empr.RoleId = rn.RoleId ;
     DbAccess.Data.EmpRoles.AddObject(empr);
     DbAccess.Commit();
     break;
}
```

Comment: you mean i have to select the SNO column which is a Unique Key in the RoleName table... like  "select sno,RoleId form RoleName where roleName like '"+strDesignatio+"'...   Actually i don't need the Sno here...

Comment: Yes if RoleName has property SNo.

Comment: can you explain if you please how to create complex type with one property

Comment: "select Sno,RoleId from RoleName where roleName like '"+strDesignation+"'";       -----------when i wrote the above Code it showing some another error like .....The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MyOrgDBModel.RoleName'. A member of the type, 'RoleName1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.------- please tell me can we chage the field names of the DataReader...

Comment: Thank you Mr.Waqar.. It's helped me lot how to think and improve progarming skills .. Thank you Once again..

Comment: @VGSNaidu If the answer solved your issue, please select it as your answer.